# iOS TableView crash don't know how. Here is the app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, crash

In my app that you can download here: http://ge.tt/2DDqfJa

I've started a discussion but is died here [iOS TableView crash loading different data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615321/ios-tableview-crash-loading-different-data)

The problem is when I back from viewing the YouTube video to the recipes list, the app crash...

And when i select a category for the second time, where have to load a tableview with different data source, it crash.

This is the crash log

Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00f0da63 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x04b27ca0 in ?? ()
#2  0x00002665 in -[RecipesListController viewWillAppear:] (self=0x4b38a00, _cmd=0x6d81a2, animated=1 '\001') at /Users/claudiocanino/Documents/iOS/CottoMangiato/Classes/RecipesListController.m:67
#3  0x00370c9a in -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] ()
#4  0x0036b606 in -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] ()
#5  0x0037283e in -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] ()
#6  0x04f49549 in -[UINavigationControllerAccessibility(SafeCategory) pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] ()
#7  0x0036b4a0 in -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] ()
#8  0x00003919 in -[CategoryViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] (self=0x4b27ca0, _cmd=0x6d19e3, tableView=0x500c200, indexPath=0x4b2d650) at /Users/claudiocanino/Documents/iOS/CottoMangiato/Classes/CategoryViewCotroller.m:104
#9  0x0032a794 in -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] ()
#10 0x00320d50 in -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] ()
#11 0x000337f6 in __NSFireDelayedPerform ()
#12 0x00d8cfe3 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#13 0x00d8e594 in __CFRunLoopDoTimer ()
#14 0x00ceacc9 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#15 0x00cea240 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#16 0x00cea161 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#17 0x016e0268 in GSEventRunModal ()
#18 0x016e032d in GSEventRun ()
#19 0x002c342e in UIApplicationMain ()
#20 0x00001c08 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffef58) at /Users/claudiocanino/Documents/iOS/CottoMangiato/main.m:15
```

Another bt log:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00cd76a1 in __CFBasicHashDeallocate ()
#1  0x00cc2bcb in _CFRelease ()
#2  0x00002dd6 in -[RecipesListController setRecipesArray:] (self=0x6834d50, _cmd=0x4293, _value=0x4e3bc70) at /Users/claudiocanino/Documents/iOS/CottoMangiato/Classes/RecipesListController.m:16
#3  0x00002665 in -[RecipesListController viewWillAppear:] (self=0x6834d50, _cmd=0x6d81a2, animated=1 '\001') at /Users/claudiocanino/Documents/iOS/CottoMangiato/Classes/RecipesListController.m:67
#4  0x00370c9a in -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] ()
#5  0x0036b606 in -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] ()
#6  0x0037283e in -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] ()
#7  0x091ac549 in -[UINavigationControllerAccessibility(SafeCategory) pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] ()
#8  0x0036b4a0 in -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] ()
#9  0x00003919 in -[CategoryViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] (self=0x4b12970, _cmd=0x6d19e3, tableView=0x5014400, indexPath=0x4b2bd00) at /Users/claudiocanino/Documents/iOS/CottoMangiato/Classes/CategoryViewCotroller.m:104
#10 0x0032a794 in -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] ()
#11 0x00320d50 in -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] ()
#12 0x000337f6 in __NSFireDelayedPerform ()
#13 0x00d8cfe3 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#14 0x00d8e594 in __CFRunLoopDoTimer ()
#15 0x00ceacc9 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#16 0x00cea240 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#17 0x00cea161 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#18 0x016e0268 in GSEventRunModal ()
#19 0x016e032d in GSEventRun ()
#20 0x002c342e in UIApplicationMain ()
#21 0x00001c08 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffef58) at /Users/claudiocanino/Documents/iOS/CottoMangiato/main.m:15
```

Thanks

Comment: You could have just added these as updates to your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615321/ios-tableview-crash-loading-different-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are over-releasing objects. Since you're using retain-properties you haven't to release the object when assigning a new object to the property. The old object will be released automatically. So these lines make no sense, delete them:

```
if (self.recipesArray != nil) {

    // Release the arrays
    [self.recipesArray release];
    [self.recipesNames release];
}
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (`RecipesListController`) you are releasing rowString. There's no need to do that here. Delete that line and everything should work properly.

Answer (score 2):

You have probably tried to access an object which has been released. Search for "NSZombieEnabled" and read up on how to debug over-release problems.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've enabled the zombie to get more infos

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

self.recipesArray = dict;

[dict release];
```

in your RecipesListController.m file check 55 line  in viewwill appear you are release the object that you never give memory

when i make comment to 
//[self.recipesArray release];
//[self.recipesNames release];
then it crash on tableview row check it

Comment: Them were useless, you're right. I'm learning and I was missing why. Tnx